# how to order a text file without using array and query

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to order a text file which contain numbers and rewrite it in other textile without using query of array

i try to do it using a comparing statement but in the end it only write one number in the new text file

to make it clear the program is to find the median number in that file which is something i can't do without reordering the file descending or ascending

This is what i did

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sw As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("Numbers.txt")
    Dim sr As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText("Numbers2.txt")
    Dim num As Double
    Dim min As Double = CDbl(sw.ReadLine)
    Dim line As String = sw.ReadLine
    Do Until sw.EndOfStream
        num = CDbl(sw.ReadLine)
        If min > num Then
            sr.WriteLine(num)
        End If
    Loop
    sr.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: So... why do you not want to parse the data into an array?

Comment: I want to see if I can use another way than parse the data into an array

Comment: You could bubble-sort the data with multiple passes over two alternating output files.

Comment: should i leave the comparing statement to do that or delete it?

Comment: You need a container to sort your number. Array or List or something similar.

Comment: If you don't use a structure such as datatable, array, etc. you can use DOS shell to perform the sort for you outside your program and generate a new file that you can process.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of curse I have no idea how your text file looks, I can't help without his string format
So I made two functions who will help about the median program

> the program is to find the median number in that file

You can test this code just add 1 button in a frame that's all (I wrote some strings for test, you can change it)

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Button1.Text = "20; 30; 50; 40; 10; 80; 90; 70" Then 'A pair list of simple numbers
        Button1.Text = "20; 30; 50; 40; 80; 90; 70" 'Odd list of simple numbers
    Else
        If Button1.Text = "20; 30; 50; 40; 80; 90; 70" Then
            Button1.Text = "18; 91,123; 47,789; 29; 35; 78.456; 91; 84" 'A test with a mix of some decimal separators mistakes
        Else
            If Button1.Text = "18; 91,123; 47,789; 29; 35; 78.456; 91; 84" Then
                Button1.Text = "25.45; 78; 10.123; 65; 27.485; 78; 19; 41; 26" 'Another odd test
            Else
                Button1.Text = "20; 30; 50; 40; 10; 80; 90; 70"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Dim StringList As String = Button1.Text
    Me.Text = "Medan of " & StringList & " = " & MedianOf(StringList, "; ") 'Using "; " (; + space) separator (can be changed)
End Sub

Private Function MedianOf(ByVal StrLine As String, ByVal Separator As String) As Double
    Dim Nb As Double
    Dim Str As String = StrLine

    'Write all values in the good order with the next function down here e.g.(from "23; 12; 78; ..." to "12; 23; 78; ...")
    StrLine = GetOrderOf(StrLine, Separator)

    'Counts how many values StrLine contains
    Dim ValuesInString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(StrLine, "\" & Separator).GetUpperBound(0) + 1

    'Check ValuesInString count odd's (calculated with different ways)
    If ((ValuesInString And 1) = 1) = True Then
        Nb = CDbl(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(StrLine, "\" & Separator)(ValuesInString \ 2))
        MessageBox.Show("ODD:" & Environment.NewLine & "First String =       " & Str & Environment.NewLine & "Ordered string = " & StrLine & Environment.NewLine & "***  Median value = " & Nb & " ***")
    Else
        Nb = (CDbl(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(StrLine, "\" & Separator)((ValuesInString / 2) - 1)) + CDbl(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(StrLine, "\" & Separator)(ValuesInString / 2))) / 2
        MessageBox.Show("PAIR:" & Environment.NewLine & "First String =       " & Str & Environment.NewLine & "Ordered string = " & StrLine & Environment.NewLine & "(" & StrLine.Split(Separator)((ValuesInString / 2) - 1) & "+" & StrLine.Split(Separator)(ValuesInString / 2) & ")/2 = " & Nb)
    End If
    'MessagesBoxes were added only for a best understanding of how it works
    'Should be disabled if tests are ok

    Return Nb
End Function

Private Function GetOrderOf(ByVal Line As String, ByVal Separator As String) As String
    If Separator = "." Or Separator = "," Then MessageBox.Show("Wrong... so Wrong separator")
    Line = Line.Replace(".", ",")
    Dim Line_InOrder As String = ""
    Dim Str As String = ""
    Dim Nb As Double = 0
    Do While Line.Length > 0
        Nb = 0
        If Line.Contains(Separator) Then
            For Each St As String In System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(Line, "\" & Separator)
                If CDbl(St) > Nb Then
                    Nb = CDbl(St)
                    Str = St
                End If
            Next
        Else
            Str = Line
            Line &= Separator
        End If
        If Line.Contains(Str & Separator) Then
            Line = Replace(Line, Str & Separator, "", , 1)
        Else
            Line = Replace(Line, Separator & Str, "", , 1)
        End If

        If Line_InOrder.Length = 0 Then
            Line_InOrder = Str
        Else
            Line_InOrder = Str & Separator & Line_InOrder
        End If
    Loop
    Return Line_InOrder
End Function
```